# How to use where condition in both the table in UNION query?

Tags: mysql, union

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`. In both the tables, columns are almost the same. What I am doing is I have to display the records from both the table.

Like I am on list page and I have to display the records. Also, I have to use the where condition.

I tried below query

```
$query1='select *,(CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END) as status from tbl_lead as l1 UNION select *,(CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END) as status from tbl_leadUpload as l2';
```

Now I have to use the where condition for table 1 `where leadstatus IN(1,2,3)` and for the table2 `where leadstatus IN(1,2,3,4,7)` to display the records on the same list.

How can I use the where condition for both the table?

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tbl_lead  and tbl_leadupload have the same column (number and corresponding data type)
you shoudl add  each where at the proper table

```
    $query1='select *
      , CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END as status 
    from tbl_lead 
    WHERE leadstatus IN (1,2,3)
    UNION 
    select *
      ,CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END
    from tbl_leadUpload
    where leadstatus IN (1,2,3,4,7) ;';'
```

if not  you should use explicit column eg:

```
    $query1='select col1, col2, col3
      , (CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END) as status 
    from tbl_lead 
    WHERE leadstatus IN (1,2,3)
    UNION 
    select col1, col2, null
      ,(CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END)
    from tbl_leadUpload
    where leadstatus IN (1,2,3,4,7) ;';'
```

Comment: Actually I am getting the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN(1,2,3)' at line 13

Comment: i juts added  a space between IN and ( because  IN( whitout space  is wrong (hope this work ... )

Comment: In the first table, I have 10 columns and in the second table, I have 15 columns.

Comment: "Almost the same"  is not "exactly the same "  fwith corresponding datatype

Comment: answer  already updated ..  you must  explicitally add  the column name  ..  you must have the same number  of column with corresponding datatype  ..  if not you can use null  whre mssing

Comment: Let me try the second option. Give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, second solution is working. for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have different conditions so you have to use `WHERE` twice:

```
select *,(CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END) as status 
from tbl_lead as l1 
where leadstatus IN(1,2,3)
UNION 
select *,(CASE WHEN is_status =0 THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END) as status 
from tbl_leadUpload as l2
where leadstatus IN(1,2,3,4,7)
```

Comment: Give me some time to check this

Comment: What if I have the same condition then?

Comment: You still could use it twice or wrap everything with subquery and use `WHERE` once, but still the condition will be applied for both tables

Comment: Actually I am getting the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN(1,2,3)' at line 13